# Lower bound for $(1+x)^n$

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, upper-lower-bounds, eulers-method

I am trying to prove the following bound for $n \in N$ and $x \in [-1,0)$, but x closer to 0:

$ e^{nx} - \frac{1}{2}nx^{2}e^{(n-1)x} \leq (1+x)^n $

I have:

$ e^{nx} - \frac{1}{2}nx^{2}e^{(n-1)x} = (1 - \frac{1}{2}nx^{2}e^{-x})e^{nx} \leq 1 - \frac{1}{2}nx^{2}e^{-x} \leq 1 - x(\frac{nx}{2}) $

And looking at some limit representation for $e$ or some $e$ Taylor expansion but I am stuck.

Comment: Hint: taylor expand $(1 - \frac{1}{2}nx^{2}e^{-x})e^{nx}$ and $(1+x)^n$, and compare

Comment: In line 4 you are multiplying the inequality $e^{nx} <1$ by a negative number when $n$ is large. ($1-\frac  1 2 nx^{2} <0$ for such $n$). The inequality sign reverses when you multiply by  a negative number.

Comment: The inequality **does not hold** for $-r<x<0$ and all $n$ whatever $r>0$ is. To make it true you have to take $x$ close to $0$ depending on $n$: You can find $r_n>0$ such that the inequality hods for $-r_n<x<0$.

Comment: You are right about that, I will include it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Fisrt, lets make $x = x_n < 0$ such that $1 - \frac{1}{2}nx^2e^{-x} > 0$ then consider the following taylor expansions:

$(1+x)^n = 1 + xn + \frac{1}{2}nx^2 + (n^3 - 3n^2 -2n)\frac{x^3}{3} + O(x^4)$

$e^{nx} - \frac{1}{2}nx^2e^{(n-1)x} = 1 + xn + \frac{1}{2}nx^2 + (2n^3 - 6n^2 + 6n)\frac{x^3}{3} + O(x^4)$

Substracting them we obtain:

$(1+x)^n - (e^{nx} - \frac{1}{2}nx^2e^{(n-1)x}) = (n^3 - 3n^2 -2n)\frac{x^3}{3} - (2n^3 - 6n^2 + 6n)\frac{x^3}{3} + O(x^4)$

We just have to proove that

$(n^3 - 3n^2 -2n)\frac{x^3}{3} - (2n^3 - 6n^2 + 6n)\frac{x^3}{3} \geq 0$

i.e.

$(n^3 - 3n^2 -2n)\frac{x^3}{3} \geq (2n^3 - 6n^2 + 6n)\frac{x^3}{3}$

i.e.

$(n^3 - 3n^2 -2n) \leq (2n^3 - 6n^2 + 6n) \iff (n^3 - 3n^2 + 8n) \geq 0 $

It should be trivial that for $n \geq 0$ the cubic polynomial images are above $0$, and in $0$ it is exactly $0$.
$\blacksquare$

Comment: The only tiny step was just let go the 4rth order error, we could be able to depreciate it since the 3rth order difference should be bigger, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For $x\in [-1,0)$, we have
$$(1-x)^n\geq 1^n=1$$
and (as you suggested)
$$e^{nx}-\tfrac{1}{2}nx^2e^{(n-1)x}\leq 1-\frac{1}{2}nx^2e^{-x}\leq 1.$$
The result immediately follows.

Comment: I edited the cuestion, that chances everithing, sorry for the inconvenience